# Is there syntax to prevent instances of a class being const?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constants, mutable

Let's say that I create a class where the primary use case will have the user always calling methods that modify its members. Or, looking at it another way, creating a class where every method will modify a class member(s).

For example, let's work with this dummy class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void setM_1(int);
    void setM_2(char);
    void setM_3(float);

private:
    int     m_1;
    char    m_2;
    float   m_3;
};
```

For this `Foo` class, creating a `const` instance of it doesn't make sense, since every method is guaranteed to modify a member.

My goal is this: define this class in such a way that `const`-ly instantiating this class would have no effect. That is to say, a `const Foo` instance would be able to call every method that a `Foo` instance can.

I was able to achieve this behavior by marking every method `const`, declaring all non-`const` members `mutable`, and providing a ctor that initialized all members of the class.

So the `const`-ignorant version of `Foo` looks like:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        m_1 = 0;
        m_2 = '\0';
        m_3 = 0.0f;
    }

    void setM_1(int)   const;
    void setM_2(char)  const;
    void setM_3(float) const;

private:
    mutable int     m_1;
    mutable char    m_2;
    mutable float   m_3;
};
```

My question is this: is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Or, is this just bad class design? (no debates please).

**After Answer Edit:**
It's official: I just took a brain crap.

Kerrek SB is right: creating a `const Foo` and using class-modifying methods would raise compiler errors anyways, so my "`const`-ignorant" Foo is pointless.

A little documentation would solve my "problem".

No wonder I had a hunch that this was terrible class design.

Excuse me everyone, this question must've been an eyesore. Thank you for the constructive criticism.

Comment: Thankfully the answer is no.

Comment: No debates please, he says asking an inherently completely subjective and open-ended question.

Comment: This seems pointless. You will already get a compiler error if you ever create a (non-dead) instance of this class. What more do you want?

Comment: `Or, is this just bad class design?` Yes, this. Just curious, do you have any particular application in mind for what you are asking?

Comment: I don't see when the ability to create a `const` instance would be harmful that you would want to prevent it. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Even if all methods of the class will mutate the state, there still might be some value in having a `const` class object - for example to use for creating new objects with a particular starting state (the GOF Protoype pattern).

Comment: The GOF couldn't write a useful pattern to save their lives. More relevantly, this begs how normal operations like copying would work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your goal is fundamentally incorrect. `const` exists not for funsies, but because it means that you really need `const`. Such a class would break horribly as e.g. a set key- where mutating it would break the ordering. There are other pitfalls like what happens when you provide it as a temporary in certain cases.

If your class cannot be realistically used in a `const` way, the interface should not lie about it and pretend that it's `const` when it isn't.

As for your question about bad design, I can safely say that yes, this sounds like a truly terrible design.

Answer (score 1):

No, thank frak.

This makes no sense and would be extremely confusing/dangerous.

**If you don't think it makes sense to have a `const T` *then don't instantiate a `const T`*.**

Comment: Bah, C++ is teh suckz. Why doesn't it stop me from writing bad code!

Answer (score 0):

From a language point of view, what bad things will happen if a class cannot be const:

First of all, is it that declaring an L-value of type const for it is not allowed, or that const references to it are also prohibited?

If you do not have const reference, then you won't have the default copy constructor, or copy assignment operator. You can't have the class be a member of any other class either, unless that also cannot be const.

I have seen some (sloppy) code where people implement iterators, and because they get tired of writing boilerplate, they implement const_iterators by const_casting away the const and using the non-const iterator implementation. They do this with classes that they know won't "actually" be const, so it won't be undefined behavior in their program. Potentially, not much fun for maintainers though.

For these classes, the class "cannot be const" in the sense that if you actually created a const one on the stack and used it normally you could technically get UB.

If what you want is for the compiler to complain when someone creates a const instance of some class, I think that doesn't really make sense. Const is fundamentally a "promise not to change something". Why would you want to forbid the programmer from making a promise about how he will use something, that seems only beneficial.